# Get the newly generated URL in python 3 after some request?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the newly generated URL of any site after posting/requesting something in its search bar, but facing some difficulties. Here is my code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")

    username = driver.find_element_by_name("field-keywords")
    username.send_keys("samsung s8")
    driver.find_element_by_name("field-keywords").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    print(driver.current_url)
```

i expect it to display "https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=samsung+s8" as output but it shows https://www.amazon.com/.

and if i replace this line

```
    driver.find_element_by_name("field-keywords").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

with this line

```
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("nav-input").click()
```

it works fine.
i want to get the new URL without using click() function, because for this i also have to get the search button's id/name to perform click whereas in case of "Keys.ENTER" i just need search bar's id, which makes my code more generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the Firefox driver it displays https://www.amazon.com because firefox took time load whole content so the current Url gets printed

This works fine with chrome driver at my side:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")

username = driver.find_element_by_name("field-keywords")
username.send_keys("samsung s8")
username.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
print(driver.current_url)
```

With the Firefox driver, To display the current url I made it sleep for some second with the time module and it works fine

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com")

username = driver.find_element_by_name("field-keywords")
username.send_keys("samsung s8")
username.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(10)
print(driver.current_url)
```